# How to generate a random combination of digits that are already defined in Pascal?

Tags: random, pascal

I would like to ask if anybody can give a hand in solving the following issue: How should I use the random function in Pascal in order to generate a random combination of digits that are already initialized (I mean that I have given values to four variables and I want via the random function to create a random combination of these four digits).
Thanks in advance!

Rossi

Comment: It's a little unclear. Do you want to use each of the four digits once and only once in each result? Or just a random pick of 4 and possibly repeat some whilst neglecting others from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

```
   var digits : array[0..3] of integer = (10,20,30,40);
       i      : integer;

   begin
      Randomize;  // initialize the random generator. Only once per program
      for i:=0 to 50 do
        Writeln(digits[random(4)]);   
   end.
```

The Writeln line draws a number 0<=x<4 so 0..3, and looks it up in the digits array, then writes it to console output. It is draws 50 random numbers and then quits.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, Lurker! Actually i want to make a little program where: I define de value of four variables in the beginnig (for example x1:= 2; x2:= 4; x3:= 2 and x4:=9), then i want the computer to generate a combination of these 4 digits on a random basis (for example 2249 or 9224 etc.). Further in the program the user of the program has to guess this combination. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well let me give you a hint.   13= 1*10 + 3*1

Answer (score 0):

```
var
randomnumber,i:integer;
number:array[0..3] of integer; 

begin
    randomize;
    for i:= 0 to 3 do
    begin
        readln(number[i]);
    end;

    randomnumber:= (number[random(4)] * 1000) + (number[random(4)] * 100) + (number[random(4)] * 10) + (number[random(4)] * 1);
    writeln(randomnumber);

end.
```

I hope this could help.
But the given initial value should be between 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the output contains each digit only once, then you would need to stored the digits which have already been chosen in a set to prevent them from being chosen again.

```
const
 digits: array [0..3] of integer = (1, 3, 5, 7); 

var
 i, n, total: integer;
 stored: set of integer;

begin
 Randomize;  
 stored:= [];
 total:= 0;
 for i:= 1 to 4 do
  begin
   repeat
    n:= random (4);
   until not (n in stored);
   stored:= stored + [n];
   total:= total * 10 + digits[n];
  end;
 writeln (total)
end.
```